# Nested Nears with Sphinx and Thinking_Sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have a RAILS 3.0.10 application (using Ruby 1.9.2) that using the thinking_sphinx gem. Is it possible in the extended match mode to use the "or" operator 
with the "near" operator so that thinking_sphinx will find text with 
either word in group 1 within a specified proximity to either word in 
group 2. For example, '(pro | support | apologist | backer | stalwart 
| proponent | patron | partisan | hero | leader | martyr | aimed | 
stop) NEAR/30 people' ? I am using sphinx 0.9.9-release.

Answer (score 0):

ThinkingSphinx.search "pro support apologist", :match_mode => :any